# Javascript collision detection issue

Tags: javascript, class, methods

I have a class with this collisionDetection method:

```
wallCollisionDetection(){
    if((this.position.x >= canvasWidth-this.radius) || (this.position.x <= this.radius) ){
        this.speed.x = -this.speed.x
    }
    
    if((this.position.y >= canvasHeight-this.radius) || (this.position.y <= this.rafius) ){
        this.speed.y = -this.speed.y
    }
}
```

Simple enough and it works.
From time to time (rarely but still), when the particle hits a vertical wall, it tends to just move vertically, stuck to that wall.
Same, when it hits a horizontal wall (then it tends to only move horizontally).

As a reference, if I generate 200 particles and let them move randomly for 5 minutes, an average 2 of them will be stuck in one direction.

I think this code sample should be enough since there is no error thrown. So I believe I'm just missing some extra condition in that method. But if you consider you need more, just ask for it.

Comment: Did you mean for your initial checks to be `>=` for both. just like the second test?

Comment: and you have a typo in `this.rafius`

Comment: If they are crawling the edges then they're stuck on 0

Comment: Oh, yes, the zero case isn't dealt with, it's true.
But it's strange since the speed is computed like this: 
this.speed = {x: (Math.random()/this.mass), y: (Math.random()/this.mass)};
It's hard to believe that a floating random number would ever be exactly 0 Could it ? I didn't consider this because it seemed highly unlikely.

Comment: Changed the typo, thanks.

Comment: @scunliffe: what do you mean about ">=" ? I made a mistake there?
I check first for ">" and then for "<=". If it's a mistake, just tell me. Thanks.

Comment: @zer00n: i Juste check and created a marker : if speed = 0 then color change. When a particle is stuck, there is no color change and it doesn't seem NOT to move in one direction, it's just seem to fluctuate around a fixed value and be stuck in that limbo. So it seems that the zero use case is not the culprit?

Comment: @BachirMessaouri my presumption is that you want to test when your circular object "hits" a wall, to bounce it in the other direction... depending on *when* you check, you may be *exactly* at the wall, or slightly passed it. As such, we typically check if the ball is `<=` to the left edge, and `>=` to the right edge, and ditto for vertical... the `<` only check would fail if you are *right at* the edge.

Comment: Does is get stuck on all edges? or just some... if so, which edges?

Comment: @scunliffe: Ah, that totally makes sense! that seem to be a good lead. I'll try that and get back to you. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, all edges can have it happen. But I think your previous assumption is right. I'm about to test it.

Comment: @BachirMessaouri yeah as a float the odds are slim to reach zero.

Comment: Do you have more of the code that you could post?  Alternatively if you could add some logging it might help… if the position is within 5pm of an edge… log the x,y to the console (just to verify if the value fluctuates or if you get some weir (0, NaN) type thing)

Comment: @scunliffe: just tried and changed ">" to ">=" (see edited code in the original post). I still get stuck particles on the wall. Last try, I had 5 of them stuck among 200 particles. But you are onto something here since all the stuck particles have crossed the walls to a certain degree. So it seems the code still let some pass the walls between frames and doesn't know how to deal with that afterwards?

Comment: Ok, I'll try to post everything and log what I can.

Comment: Ah ok now this is becoming clear… set a variable for your minX, minY, maxX, maxY for as far as each boundary is… when you change directions, force set the x/y accordingly to the edge you’re on… so that if the ball went passed the edge it is brought back in… I think you have case where it goes passed then on every iteration it just wobbles, just beyond the edge

Comment: Just seen your last comment after I posted my answer. It seems that I made what you just suggested but in a more naïve way. Less pretty but it seems to work. I don't know how to reward you for the help. Anyway, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, scunliffe showed me the way.
It seems that when a particle goes over the boundary, it remains stuck in an infinite "if" loop.

So here is how it solved it (basically, I just set the position to its maximum/minimum allowed value so that the loop doesn't happen):

```
wallCollisionDetection(){

    if(this.position.x > canvasWidth-this.radius){
        this.position.x = canvasWidth-this.radius;
        this.speed.x = -this.speed.x
    }
    else if(this.position.x < this.radius){
        this.position.x = this.radius
        this.speed.x = -this.speed.x
    }

    if(this.position.y > canvasHeight-this.radius ){
        this.position.y = canvasHeight-this.radius;
        this.speed.y = -this.speed.y
    }
    else if(this.position.y < this.radius){
        this.position.y = this.radius;
        this.speed.y = -this.speed.y
    }
}
```

Not pretty but it works.
Thanks!